# Simple batch command using combine...cant get it to work

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch command that combines 2 files with the following logic:

If file A exists and File B exists, create file C and then delete file A and file B.
If file A exists, but not File B, do nothing.
If file B exists, but not File A, do nothing.

I have the following code, and it works for the most part, except for when I run this and File A exists, but File B does not exist, it still uses File A to create File C.

Disclaimer: I am not a programmer at all, its mostly greek to me. My boss wanted me to create this script.

What am I doing wrong?

```
IF EXIST C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileA.txt (
IF EXIST C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileB.txt ( 
COPY FileA.txt+FileB.txt FileC.txt 

DEL FileA.txt
DEL FileB.txt

)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the filenames, because the path to them contains spaces. It's also much better to either change to the directory containing the files, or fully qualify them every time you use them. The easiest way is just to change to the directory.

```
rem Remember the folder you start in
pushd
cd "C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents"

IF EXIST FileA.txt (
  IF EXIST FileB.txt ( 
    COPY FileA.txt+FileB.txt FileC.txt 

    DEL FileA.txt
    DEL FileB.txt

  )
) 
rem Change back to where you were before
popd
```

The more difficult way:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileA.txt" (
  IF EXIST "C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileB.txt" ( 
    COPY "C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileA.txt"+"C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileB.txt" "C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileC.txt"

    DEL "C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileA.txt"
    DEL "C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\FileB.txt"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option.

```
pushd "C:\Users\matthew jones\Documents\"
IF EXIST "FileA.txt" IF EXIST "FileB.txt" ( 
   COPY "FileA.txt"+"FileB.txt" "FileC.txt"
   DEL "FileA.txt"
   DEL "FileB.txt"
)   
popd
```